# Fetching data from XML incl. children and display in page using php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I have a XML with the following structure:

```
<item>
                      <attributes>
                <attribute datatype="text">
                    <name><![CDATA[name]]></name>
                    <value><![CDATA[Product Name]]></value>
                </attribute>
                <attribute datatype="text">
                    <name><![CDATA[sku]]></name>
                    <value><![CDATA[PRODUCTSKU]]></value>
                </attribute>
                <attribute datatype="numeric">
                    <name><![CDATA[price]]></name>
                    <value>10000</value>
                </attribute>
        <attribute datatype="numeric">
                    <name><![CDATA[eancode]]></name>
                    <value>123456789</value>
                </attribute>
            </attributes>
        </item>
```

Now, here I am looking for the following output:

```
Product Name : PRODUCTSKU : 10000 : 123456789
```

But with the following code am fetching the whole details under *attribute* node but I can't segregate the SUB NODES values...

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open( 'test.xml' );
$id = 'attributes';
while ($reader->read()) {
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
        $exp = $reader->expand();
        if ($exp->nodeName == $id)
            echo "<b>" . $exp->nodeName . " : </b>" . $exp->nodeValue . "<br />";

    }
}
```

I have also tried this with DOMDOcument also:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument(); 
$xml->load('test.xml');
$root = $xml->documentElement;
foreach($root->childNodes as $node){

    //print $node->nodeName.' - '.$node->nodeValue;
    print $node->nodeValue;
}
```

But this also displays all the sub nodes together...I want to segregate them and store into DB...please help me with this...am struggling with this quiet a long

Comment: I'm not familiar with the XMLReader class but can you call the expand function again to go a level deeper?

Comment: @scrowler...am also not very familiar with this...am using XMLReader since the file is too large and XMLReader is the best option to read such file

Comment: Can you call the expand function within your if statement again to go a level deeper? You might consider changing to use SimpleXML or DOMDocument which are also both native to PHP

Comment: @scrowler...any idea how to use DOMDocument here?

Comment: @scrowler...please see my edit in the post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to use `SimpleXML` but if you want to use `XMLReader` try this:

```
$values = array();
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open( 'test.xml' );
$id = 'attribute';
while ($reader->read()) {
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
        $exp = $reader->expand();
        if ($exp->nodeName == "item") {
            if (count($values)) print implode(" : ", $values);
            $values = array();
        }
        if ($exp->nodeName == $id) {
            foreach ($exp->childNodes as $node) {
                if ($node->nodeName == "value") {
                    $values[] = $node->textContent;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
if (count($values)) print implode(" : ", $values);
```